# How to query a nested field in wordpress api using _fields param

Tags: plugin-development, rest-api, api

I'm trying to access certain fields which are deeply nested using _fields param which is offered by wordpress.
What's wrong with my query?

structure of response.

```
{
    "_embedded" : {
    
        wp:featuredmedia : [
            {
                "id": 21917,
                 "date": "2021-02-27T11:56:48",
                 "slug": "SLUG",
                 "type": "attachment",
                 "link": "https://SITENAME.net/POST/POST/",
                  "title": {
                     rendered": "SLUG NAME"
                 },
            
            }
            
        ]
    }
}
```

Desired response :

```
{
    "_embedded" : {

        wp:featuredmedia : [
            {
                 "link": "https://SITENAME.net/POST/POST/",
            }

        ]
    }
}
```

Query I'm Trying to use:

```
http://yoursite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed&_filter=_embedded.wp:featuredmedia[0].link
```

Comment: Note that doing this doesn't speed things up on the server side, it may even slow things down as the server can't cache the result and has to process the data to get the customized version of the resource. The only saving made here is in transfer bandwidth

Comment: i see, Good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you want to use is **_fields=** not **_filter=**

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed&_fields=_links
```

I don't believe you can make fields only show _embedded thought. Best I was able to do was to make it show _links which then also shows _embedded.

Hope this helps.